# Checkbox to listview not added properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I want to create a dynamic list with image and checkbox, it's working fine, however, when I generate it dynamically at the function onload, it doesn't generate properly

My code is below [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/brBdD/20/l)

In the example there are 2 li in HTML 5 but the third li  that generate in JavaScript doesn't generate properly

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <!-- page -->
    <div id="tryhtml" data-role="page" data-palette="">
        <!-- header -->
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Application</h1>   
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-icon="none" id="FB" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
                <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
                <li>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1a" class="custom" data-iconpos="right"/>
                        <label for="checkbox-1a"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/261025_100001129460073_937883521_q.jpg" style="margin-right:20PX; float:left" width="35" height="35"/>Cheetos dffaf</label>

                </li>
                <li>

                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2a" id="checkbox-2a" class="custom" data-iconpos="right"/>
                        <label for="checkbox-2a"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/261025_100001129460073_937883521_q.jpg" style="margin-right:20PX; float:left" width="35" height="35"/>Cheetos dffaf</label>

                </li>           
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

Onload function at js file:

```
 var tag = '<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-5a" id="checkbox-5a" data-iconpos="right"/><label for="checkbox-5a"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/261025_100001129460073_937883521_q.jpg" style="margin-right:20PX; float:left" width="35" height="35"/>Roy dffaf</label></li>';
$('#FB').append(tag);   
$('#FB').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/brBdD/21/

```
var tag = '<li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-5a" id="checkbox-5a" data-iconpos="right"/><label for="checkbox-5a"><img src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash4/261025_100001129460073_937883521_q.jpg" style="margin-right:20PX; float:left" width="35" height="35"/>Roy dffaf</label></li>';


$('#FB').append(tag);   
$('#FB').find('#checkbox-5a').checkboxradio().checkboxradio( "refresh" );
$('#FB').listview('refresh');
```

In your case **`.listview('refresh');`** will only style listview and listview only, don't forget you also have a checkbox to style. Because of how jQuery Mobile works you first want to style checkbox and then listview.

Checkbox is usually styled with **`.checkboxradio( "refresh" );`** but in this case we have a dynamically created checkbox so it first needs to be initialized with **`.checkboxradio()`**.